# How to add notifcations to front-end menu for users when they recieved replies?

Tags: menus, front-end, notifications

So I get this theme were people can interact with each other, send message, gifts, chat, etc.

I want the menu, or the button "My profile" to change and add a notification symbol, notifiying the user that someone has interacted with your profile.

Basically just like how stackexchanges uses their notifications on the menu.

Is this possible with a plugin or would you have to fix it with jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the specifics of your theme I can't say if a plugin exists that does this.  That said, if you are comfortable with PHP something like this would do the trick:
`My Profile<?php if($user->hasMessages()):><img src="/path/to/icon"><?php endif;?>`
Do you have a code sample to look at, I could be much more specific if you did.